# Listening to AngularJS controller initialization event externally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller (say main controller) which controls the main page and also maintains all event listeners, like `$locationChangeSuccess`, etc.

I have a few more controllers that are referenced in partials which get included to the main page using `ng-include`. This is wrapped around with some custom routing logic that allows me to decide which partial to load. This also changes the url accordingly.

I can listen to location changes using `$locationChangeSuccess` event. However, that does not guarantee that the controller corresponding to the partial which got loaded through `ng-include` has been initialized.

I know we can use `$viewContentLoaded` on `$scope` of partial's controller for this. However, I necessarily need to avoid putting any event listeners outside of the main controller. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag like $scope.$parent.inited = true; as the first line of the subcontrollers and then in the main controller $scope.inited = false; you could use a watch to check for that flag and call some functions once done, then set it to false once you click to go other substates and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Santiago. Ideally, I would like to keep the subcontrollers free from any boiler plate code like `$scope.$parent.inited = true`. Is there any other way for the main controller to detect that a page load after location change has fully completed?

Comment: you could emit and event from your subcontrollers and listen it as you are doing from the main one

Comment: I would like to avoid any event related logic from going into subcontrollers. BTW, I was able to figure out that listening to `$includeContentLoaded` from the main controller solves my problem.